# Swift 3 - How to read a json output from an index that contains a string

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm using an api to get some json information, here is an example what it looks like:

```
multimedia: [
{
  url: "small.jpg"
  format: "small"
},
{
  url: "medium.jpg"
  format: "medium"
},
{ url: "large.jpg"
  format: "large"
}  
]
```

so as you can see the multimedia container has many image urls with different sizes, and I want to read only one of them for example only the url for the medium.jpg.

My code is something like this that reads the multimedia container first:

```
let randomImg = result[random]["multimedia"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Then  I made another variable which reads the index I want:

```
let randomImgIndex = randomImg[1]
```

so when I try to get my final string I get error:

```
let finalImgUrl = randomImgIndex[random]["url"] as! String
```

Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'Int'

I am very new to swift so I'm totally lost.

Comment: Swift 4 has `Decodable` which makes things like this extremely easy. Any reason why you are holding off upgrading to Swift 4?

Comment: well I was taught using swift 3 so I kinda had to stick with it and didn't feel confident jumping to swift 4 when I was kinda adapted to swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randomImgIndex` is already the desired dictionary.

Change:

```
let finalImgUrl = randomImgIndex[random]["url"] as! String
```

to:

```
let finalImgUrl = randomImgIndex["url"] as! String
```

On a side note, you need to stop using all of those `!` and `as!` operators. Your app will crash if the data isn't exactly as expected. Code defensively when you are obtaining data beyond your control.

Comment: thank you, that did it. And ill try to follow that advice, its just usually when something doesn't work I noticed using ! ? etc sometimes fixes it so I kind of caught a habit doing that.